# subtract a fixed amount from a number in an xml with find/replace in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

It seems like I can't understand much of the notepad++ wiki, and I can't find  similar question here.
The problem:

```
type="0" x="184" y="698" w="245" h="7"
```

So I'm trying to add or subtract an amount from these coordinates, for example I want to add 10 to y="698" so that it becomes y="708"
I'm sure there has to be a way, but I'm to much of a novice to understand it from resources available on the internet.

Comment: You can't do math operations with regular expressions alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this can be done using just regular expressions.

If you need to do it just once or twice, paste the data into Excel, use text to columns, do the math, then paste it back.

If this is a common task, then consider writing a dedicated script for it.

Comment: thx for the suggestion